# Bootstrap 4 navbar doesnt collapse on tablet

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, responsive-design

I have downloaded and customized a simple bootstrap 4 theme.
Under customized, i mean i added same margin to the meni items, and i added my logo.

My problem is, that on tablets, the navbar is not collapsign, i attach a photo of it.

[And you can view my demo site here.](https://betontermekem.hu/)

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-white" id="site_navigation"> 
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="<?php echo $host; ?>" title="">
        <img src="<?php echo $host; ?>/images/assets/logo2.png" class="img-responsive site_logo" alt=""/>
    </a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarsExampleDefault" aria-controls="navbarsExampleDefault" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation"> 
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"><i class="fa fa-bars navbar_ikon"></i></span>
    </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarsExampleDefault">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item dropdown"> <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="http://example.com" id="dropdown01" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Szolgáltatások</a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown01"> <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a> <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a> <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a> </div>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown"> <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="http://example.com" id="dropdown01" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Bemutatkozás</a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown01"> <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a> <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a> <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a> </div>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="<?php echo $host; ?>/webaruhaz-keszites">Webáruház készítés</a> </li>
      <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">Referenciák</a> </li>
      
    </ul>
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
      <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav_link_last_1" href="#"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> Kapcsolatfelvétel</a> </li>  
      <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav_link_last_2" href="#"><i class="fa fa-file"></i> Árajánlat kérése</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Photo here. Where is the logo on tablet, and whats happening with the menu items?
[image: Photo here. Where is the logo on tablet, and whats happening with the menu items?]

Comment: It works for me though: http://mobiletest.me/ipad_mini_emulator/?u=https://betontermekem.hu/#
You can also test the responsiveness via developer console or Shortcut (Ctrl+Shift+M)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is normal because the collapse is happening at 992px. And when you check landscape view on your tablet, probably it is over this limit. Even with browser inspect tools, it is showing it this way. So just set class expand `xl` instead of `lg`.

Or you can set smaller `font-size`.

Comment: What does the expand-xl do? I mean, if my pc's monitor only have 1024x768px resolution, the navigation will be hided, and only the navbar toggler button will  be shown?

Comment: Yes this is why I think that managing `font-size` is not a bad idea because the same view will be shown on screen laptop

Comment: @steve777 Have a look to: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/content/typography

Comment: Font size? It isnt big. Why should i brint it smaller?

Comment: Because your pictos will become align with text at least when it is under 1024px. Maybe try with vw unit

Comment: Or, will it help, if i delete one menu item?

Answer (score 0):

Well you have the problem only in landscape mode right?

### Solution #1

Change `navbar-expand-lg` to `navbar-expand-xl`

### Solution #2

Set a new breakpoint with the width of the iPad in landscape mode in your .css and copy the css of your navbar from the next lower breakpoint.

I think it should be 1024px so:

```
@media (min-width: 1024px){

}
```

You can also combine two breakpoints and make a breakpoint with min-width and max-width of 1024 for example, so it just fits for exactly this width.